# Why does my character echo wait for a newline, echoing the whole string instead of char-for-char

Tags: haskell

Little snip of code that I expect because I'm using the char get/put methods should respond on every input character, but that doesn't appear to be the case; rather it waits for a newline and then runs the whole string which doesn't altogether make sense to me...

What am I doing wrong? How do I get this to react on each input character?

```
main = repeatUntilExit stdin stdout putChar ""

repeatUntilExit :: Handle -> Handle -> (Char -> IO ()) -> [Char] -> IO ()
repeatUntilExit hIn hOut f "exit\n" = hPutStrLn hOut "bye\n"
repeatUntilExit hIn hOut f x = hGetChar hIn >>= \c -> f c >> repeatUntilExit hIn hOut f (appendToLastFive c)
  where appendToLastFive a = (reverse . (:)a . take 4 . reverse) x
```

the results are:

```
C:\temp>echo.exe
an entire line of text
an entire line of text
exit
exit
bye

C:\temp>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a [buffering](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/latest/html/libraries/base-4.6.0.1/System-IO.html#g:12) question.

```
import System.IO

hSetBuffering stdin NoBuffering
```

This does not however work on windows, still an unfixed issue noted [here](http://hackage.haskell.org/trac/ghc/ticket/2189).

Comment: Thanks for all the help dave, you're just trolling the haskell tag better than anyone lately it appears

Comment: You have this unerring ability to post a question just before I check the haskell tag. It's quite bemusing.